# Batch file or similar to automate disconnecting/spin-down multiple external hdd's

Tags: windows-10, batch, external-hard-drive, automation

How to create a batch file, or some other 'automated' method that will allow me to safely spin down multiple external HDD's so that I can switch off their power strip(s) when I am done accessing them?

I'm looking for a batch file, or similar, to automate the spin-down  of connected external hdd's, or advice on how to achieve the same.

I often have 2 or 3, possibly 4 external powered hdd's connected for various needs and at various times.  These drives are all powered through power strip(s) with on/off toggle.

I now realize why simply flipping the power strip toggle off can (did!) cause issues/loss/etc.

For what it’s worth, each external drive on my system has been  assigned a specific letter.  So if any specific external drive is connected, it will always be assigned same drive letter, regardless of any other connected drives.

Comment: You refer to: a) shutdown/cut of the energy that feeds the physical unit (direct on the interface/hard disk board); b) suspending the power of the usb port that is connected to the external unit (external HD device); c) turn off the power of the USB port of the USB HUB where the external HD is plugged?

Comment: Anyway, I suggest reviewing the equipment used to save your files, since current interfaces in use are subject to data loss when turning them off, as mentioned, it would be the first action and the last, yes, it would be to apply some code that automates a secure process that suits you.

Comment: Ref a) above. Current backup procedures are simply batch files that xcopy any new or updated files from a  folder to a different given folder on an external drive. There's an xcopy for phone DCIM uploads, for example.  One for work projects.  Etc etc. Currently, I flip on the surge protector for external drives (example: drive "M" is for photos), then run the xcopy .bat file to copy all new/changed images to drive M.  I want to safely turn off (AC power) to drive M (and others) after the file transfer.   Drives are desktop, so possibly the USB port would work, if no problems with peripherals.